# using hyperlinks in java file

Tags: java, string, variables, hyperlink

I am trying to add a hyperlink in java file.

TestHyperlink.java

```
class TestHyperlink.java {
  String url = "stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
  String someVariable = "testUrl";
  Html entryLink = new Html("<a target=\"_blank\" href=url>someVariable</a>");
}
```

I am trying to use two string variables url and someVariable but I am not sure how to do it. My hyper link appears as 'someVariable' and on click leads to a broken page.

What I seek is a hyperlink which appears as testUrl and on click leads to a desired url page, [stackoverflow.com/questions/ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) in this case.

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't interpolate variables inside Strings.  You need to change to `new Html("<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"" + url + "\">" + someVariable + "</a>");`

Comment: This leads me to an about:blank page in chrome, also I want the link to appear as testUrl(value of a variable) not someVariable(not a fixed value)